# Who is "reverent-stonebraker"

Tags: ubuntu, putty, plesk, ionos

I have installed Ubuntu20.04 using the Ionos 1&1 CloudPanel.

Then I logged in to my server with Putty.

After entering the password for "root", it shows me:

```
root@reverent-stonebraker:~#
```

I googled "reverent-stonebraker", but since it didn't yield any results, I am confused what this actually means.

What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the hostname of your machine. It was generated randomly, apparently using [Docker's algorithm](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go).